# How to call a procedure with a rowtype literal as parameter in PL/SQL?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, rowtype

Lets say I have a table and a procedure that accepts one argument of the tables rowtype:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a NUMBER, b NUMBER);

CREATE PROCEDURE p (x t%ROWTYPE) IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
```

Can I call that procedure using a rowtype literal, that is without explicitly creating a rowtype variable (or at least not explicitly listing and assigning every field of it)? The two following approaches both generate the below error:

```
p(1, 2);
```

```
p((1, 2));
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also construct the record from a cursor loop:

```
for r in (
    select 1, 2 from dual
)
loop
    p(r);
end loop;
```

Unfortunately PL/SQL records are just simple structures and don't come with constructors as object types do. (I wish they did.)

Comment: Thanks! It works and gets rid of the need to declare a variable. Still not very pretty, but I have a feeling I might have to give up on that requirement.

Comment: Or, write your own constructor, i.e. a function called "new_whatever" where "whatever" is the record type, that returns a record of that type.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, since it (a) requires the creation of a variable and (b) isn't very pretty. But at least it works:

```
DECLARE
  x t%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1, 2 INTO x FROM dual;
  p(x);
END;
```

I am still interested in better solutions.