# Call a Postgresql procedure with a ROWTYPE or RECORD literal

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I'm building on a recipe book application. I'm only doing it to practice working in Postgresql:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                 version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I have several tables for storing recipe based information; one pertains to the list of ingredients:

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    quantity NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    unit TEXT,
    display_order INT NOT NULL
);
```

I'm writing a function called `save_recipe`, and this is what it looks like so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_recipe
  (
  first_name COOK.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
  last_name COOK.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
  email COOK.EMAIL%TYPE,
  recipe_name RECIPE.NAME%TYPE,
  recipe_cook_time RECIPE.COOK_TIME%TYPE,
  recipe_preface RECIPE.PREFACE%TYPE,
  instructions RECIPE.INSTRUCTIONS%TYPE,
  ingred INGREDIENT
  )
AS $$
DECLARE
  cook_id COOK.ID%TYPE;
  recipe_id RECIPE.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO cook (first_name, last_name, email)
    VALUES (first_name, last_name, email)
    RETURNING id INTO cook_id;

  INSERT INTO recipe (name, cook_id, created_at, cook_time, instructions, preface)
    VALUES (recipe_name, cook_id, now(), recipe_cook_time, instructions, recipe_preface)
    RETURNING id INTO recipe_id;

  INSERT INTO ingredient (name, quantity, unit, display_order)
    VALUES (ingred.name, ingred.quantity, ingred.unit, ingred.display_order);

  COMMIT;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Cook ID : %', cook_id;
  RAISE NOTICE 'Recipe ID : %', recipe_id;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I'm having issues creating an ingredient literal (if that's the right word). This is the best I've been able to do at this point:

```
CALL save_recipe(
  first_name => 'Joe',
  last_name => 'Fresh',
  email => 'joe@loblaws.com',
  recipe_name => 'Cherry Pie',
  recipe_cook_time => '1 hour',
  recipe_preface =>'I love cherry pie.',
  instructions => ARRAY['Make.', 'Bake.', 'Eat.'],
  ingred => (0, 'Cherry', 20, 'small, pitted', 1)
);
```

I'd like that `ingred` to be an array but my bigger concern is that I need to populate the `ingredient.id` even though I'm ignoring it during insert (because I want to use the generated IDs provided by Postgres). Is there a structure/type I can use where I don't need to specify a dummy ID like this (and that can eventually be an `ARRAY` type).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777381/how-to-call-a-procedure-with-a-rowtype-literal-as-parameter-in-pl-sql) previously, but I was hoping that there was something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the parameter as a [variadic array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) of the type. Use `unnest()` to get elements of the array as rows (the function simplified for readability):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_recipe
  (
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  email text,
  VARIADIC ingred INGREDIENT[]
  )
AS $$
DECLARE
  cook_id COOK.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO cook (first_name, last_name, email)
    VALUES (first_name, last_name, email)
    RETURNING id INTO cook_id;

  INSERT INTO ingredient (name, quantity, unit, display_order)
  SELECT i.name, i.quantity, i.unit, i.display_order
  FROM unnest(ingred) i;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Cook ID : %', cook_id;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example use:

```
CALL save_recipe(
    first_name => 'Joe',
    last_name => 'Fresh',
    email => 'joe@loblaws.com',
    variadic ingred => array[
        '(0, Apple, 2, small, 1)', 
        '(0, Pear, 5, large, 2)',
        '(0, Cherry, 20, "small, pitted", 1)'
    ]::ingredient[]
);

select *
from ingredient;

 id |  name   | quantity |      unit      | display_order
----+---------+----------+----------------+---------------
  1 |  Apple  |        2 |  small         |             1
  2 |  Pear   |        5 |  large         |             2
  3 |  Cherry |       20 |  small, pitted |             1
(3 rows)
```

Note that the procedure call may be much simpler without named parameters:

```
CALL save_recipe(
    'Joe', 'Fresh', 'joe@loblaws.com',
    '(0, Apple, 2, small, 1)', 
    '(0, Pear, 5, large, 2)',
    '(0, Cherry, 20, "small, pitted", 1)'
);
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e097791bb4231a3b4c21068738bf258)

Comment: This is likely my fault. I made too simple an example from the code I'm actually working with, and I'm not sure if `VARIADIC` will work in my case (based on what I just read). I'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks very much for revisiting the answer. I really appreciate it. It works perfectly.

Comment: I was getting an error with the insert statement into ingredient, but then I realized that I hadn't changed my original statement enough. It needed to be `INSERT INTO...SELECT...FROM...` and not `INSERT INTO...VALUES...FROM...`. Again, thank you.